# Python library for point cloud heightfields?

Tags: python, gis, interpolation, triangulation, point-clouds

Does anyone know of a good way to deal with a point cloud heightfield in python?  I've done some googling but I'm not sure if any of the results really describe what I need.  I have over 20 million points in the form of (lat, lon, altitude) (or if you'd rather, (x, y, altitude)) and want to be able to interpolate to an arbitrary position. But my experience is that a simple quadratic interpolation is terrible for altitude data.  E.g. picture the following height points, and wanting to interpolate at point X:

```
      4         3         2
4        3        2   2     0  0 
  3           2       0   0     2
      2   22      0    2   2
 2           X    2   3
   0  0  0     2         3
0          2    3             4
   2                3
```

Clearly X is down in the bottom of some sort of deep channel running ENE from the bottom left (or WSW from the top right).  But quadratic interpolation will state that X is at around height 2 - aka not in a canyon at all, but on its rim. Quadratic interpolation cares only about distance, not angle. But in terrain, angle matters a lot. If you have a distant point, and several closer points in the same direction, the distant point is virtually meaningless, but if you have a distant point in a direction with no other points in the way, that point can be very meaningful.

A good triangulation could capture the geometry, obviously - it's easy enough to interpolate a point on a triangular facet. But a Delaunay triangulation wouldn't cut it - it would just reinforce the screwup, because it doesn't like long thin shapes like canyons, and would instead prefer to tesselate the points across the edges of the canyon in the above example.

I can think up algorithms to capture the terrain well (such as "projecting" from each point with a line toward X representing a weighted slope contribution, and weakening the weighting by each point the line passes, relative to how close it passes... then doing a least-squares fit for all slopes and points).  Another option that comes to mind is using quadratic interpolation in all directions from X to get slopes in each direction, then iteratively adjusting X up or down to converge to a solution where it's not jutting unusually up or down as a whole.  But any new algorithm would probably be significant work to implement, and I hate reinventing the wheel (probably suboptimally). Surely there must be some sort of fast library that would be good for this sort of thing? Hopefully pythonic?  :)

Comment: There is the point cloud library http://pointclouds.org/ but that is in C++

Comment: In addition to it being in C++ rather than Python, does it deal with GIS-style terrain data well, particularly the above case? Or is it just a Delaunay triangulation and thus vulnerable to missing topographic details that a human can easily see, like the above case?

Comment: I did have a new algorithmic idea, which is that while my does contain isolated points, it's predominantly made from topographic isolines. So if I were to work them into a triangulation algorithm, I could use those as some of the edges of the facets, banning any disconnection of them.  (I'd still rather use an existing library if possible, though). One complication is that the lines don't appear to form complete loops, at least in the couple simple cases that I tested manually... so I can't just simply ban new edges from connecting to points of the same height.

Comment: I could possibly connect disjoint height lines by virtue of how they should contain common vertices, however.  Hmm... maybe I'll use this (https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/triangle.poly.html) as a preprocessor step and then just import the output (I'd also need to write a translator between .json and .poly)

Comment: So I'm writing a Python library for managing point clouds: https://github.com/daavoo/pyntcloud . I don't have any gis-related stuff yet but I'm looking foward to understand gis people needs. Contributions and request are welcome :).

Comment: Regarding the problem. The "point cloud heightfield" term was kind of confusing me. I did some crazy experiments trying to overfit a neural network for interpolating the 'z' value given an input point cloud. Pretty cool results. It might be worth checking that for your problem.

Comment: Wow, interesting work, fitting a neural net to a height field. To get good results I'd think you'd need to have the neural net trained on sections that are imaged in superresolution, though. Re, point cloud heightfield: GIS data is neither collected nor distributed on some perfect grid; you have a point cloud of altitude values. Re, needs: I think the above "channel" example is illustrative. Basically, if interpolating directly the interpolation needs to respect angle and obstructions. If tessellating it needs to continue shapes rather than bridging across them to make facets more "regular".

Comment: Since I'm working with processed GIS data that's been converted to topolines and peaks, only the peaks are a "true" point cloud; the topolines present additional information, in the form of the path the lines trace out (raw GIS data is generally a true point cloud).  So I'm going to give the program Triangle a shot, with the existing topolines as fixed segment constraints; I don't need to be handling new data in realtime or anything, so doing it as a preprocessing step is just fine.

Comment: But I really like your neural net concept. If you ever make a packaged version that's pretrained on high-res terrain that can be applied to tessellate a low-res terrain model, I'd love to have a copy.  :)  The task should be doable. From the large scale you can't tell the exact way that weathering will sculpt terrain on the small scale, but you can get the gist of it.  Might need to have different training datasets to reflect different weathering situations, however.

Comment: For the record for anyone who stumbles into this via Google: based on my experimenting last evening, the above approach with "constrained delaunay tesselation" via Triangle, using the height lines as constraints, looks like it's doing the trick.  :)